# View level reporting in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am in the process of onboarding an application on Google analytics, I have Dev, QA, and Prod environment.
my Dev, QA & Prod site URL's are as below:

**myapp-dev**.coolfurnace.net, **myapp-QA**.coolfurnace.net, **myapp**.coolfurnace.net

I create a property in GA4 and assign the **gtag** to my application, as as per the GIT code promotion all the sites will share the same **gtag**, how do I filter out and create the report just for my production site - **myapp.coolfurnace.net** ?

Previously in Universal analytics, we had the option to create separate views, how it works in GA4?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are no views in GA4, to see the data by isolating the domains you have to do it with the segments within the reports.